# What is minCases in C5.0Control using R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, predictive-models, decision-theory

from Package (C5.0 Decision tree Using R ) definition     "minCases : an integer for the smallest number of samples that must be put in at least two of the splits."

I very confuse about it . Please help me  to expand understand more.

Answer (score 1):

you can find the following answer on https://www.euclidean.com/machine-learning-in-practice/2015/6/12/r-caret-and-parameter-tuning-c50. I hope it helps to solve your problem.

> The minCases parameter specifies the minimum number of cases (training examples) that must be put in at least two of the splits. Essentially it controls the depth of the trees created by C5.0 (depth cannot be controlled directly) and hence it is intimately connected with the resulting tree complexity. The purpose of tuning meta parameters is to find the optimal trade-off between model complexity and the training set size and so minCases is an important parameter to tune. That said, tuning minCases is problematic under cross-validation because the number of cases in the training folds are different than the number of cases in the entire dataset so the optimal value of minCases found in cross validation will not be equal to the true optimum for the entire data set (which the final model will be trained on). To overcome this obstacle we can define minCases as a proportion of the data set size and tune the proportional parameter instead. If we define minCases as
>   `minCases <- length(y)/splits`
>   then as "splits" increases, so will the depth and complexity of the resulting trees.